# Alternative Activator.CreateInstance() using method in dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, system, dllimport

Hi I am a student studying C#.
I want to call method in MyAPI which is dll file.

Until now, I have been using it as **Activator.CreateInstance(type)**
but, Sometimes the performance is **very slow**.

Is there any alternative method? Please all of the code.

here is my code

```
Type type = null;
object obj = null;
object[] objMParam = null;

type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyAPI");
obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);   
string Name = "MethodName";
objMParam = new Object[] { par1, par2, par3 };
result = (int)type.InvokeMember(
                    Name,
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                    null,
                    obj,
                    objMParam);
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: Generally there is no way to speed up object creation. You need to figure out what exactly casing slowness in your case and fix/ask specific question. (Side note: using COM in ASP.Net is ... unusual. You'll have it *very hard* to get help with).

Comment: If your COM classes include type information, add a COM reference to your project. This will define proxy interfaces to hide all the messy create / invoke details.

Comment: And if they don't, there are ways to generate a custom COM type library